# ISO Message Representation , Wired behavior in the "pack" method in JPOS

Tags: java, iso, jpos, bit-representation

I have 2 web services .. once accepts a payload like this :

```
{
    "MTI": "0100",
    "2": "4655206331051889",
    "3": "000000",
    "4": "000000012300",
    "7": "0321054133",
    "11": "001205",
    "14": "0325",
    "18": "5399",
    "22": "022",
    "25": "00",
    "35": "2312312332",
    "37": "206305000014",
    "41": "29110001",
    "42": "1001001",
    "49": "840"
}
```

I need to generate the ISO Message Representation from it and send it to the 2nd web service that accepts payload which contains a field IsoMsg : "The Iso Message Representation Goes here" .. and then unpack it ...

The Problem is when i do pack to my first payload i got this wired representation :

```
     0100 001205 29110001
```

See ? Just MTI and 2 other fields which are field 11 and 41 .. Also there are like 3 spaces at the beginning..
Any Explanation or a another way to get it ?

Comment: The question is too vague, please provide relevant details: _how_ do you pack the payload (a code would be helpful), which result is expected?

Comment: My Problem in a straightforward way  ===> I want to generate the iso message representation from the above JSON Payload.. to be able to send it to the second web service and unpack it ..

Comment: You wrote: _when i do pack to my first payload i got this wired representation_ (should be weird).  Why this presentation is weird?  Can you show the code which implements packing? Which result would you consider to be "non-weird"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I knew what can be done : We use ISOUtil.Hex2Byte(packagedMessage)..
And the Full Representation will be generated.